# How to make a Class with Generic types inherit from a non-generic class C#

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I'm trying to make a base class that can be inherited by another class that allows generics, something like:

Base/Parent class should be something like this:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public List<string> synonims = new List<string>();
}
```

And the class that wants to inherit the base class should be something like:

```
public class ChildClass<T> where T : System.Enum
{
    public T type;
}
```

It is possible to achieve that ChildClass inherits from base class while using generic types? something like:

```
public class ChildClass<T> where T : System.Enum : BaseClass
{
    public T type;
}
```

I know that a class can only inherit from one class, but can implement multiple interfaces...but I want to know if this type of inheritance can or can't (why?) be done and how will be the syntax. Thanks.

Comment: Not what you ask, but it is a good idea to write `where T : struct, System.Enum` instead of just `System.Enum`.

Comment: okey but...why? This will let the class be created using bouth enum and struct, isn't it? If my objective was to only let the class be created from an enum, not an struct, should I use what you recommends anyway?

Comment: @Lotan It prevents you from writing `new ChildClass<Enum>()`. The generic type constraints are ANDed together, nor ORed -- it's saying that `T` must be both an `Enum`, AND a struct (which stops it from being the `Enum` type itself)

Comment: No, what I suggest, tells the compiler you want only _value types_ that inherit from `System.Enum`. So mine is more precise. If for example you want to use a nullable T, that is a `T?`, you will need my suggestion. Generally, the compiler will have an easier time if it knows in advance whether the generic argument is a reference type or a value type.

Comment: To clarify, no real "struct" that you write can fulfill the constraint that a base type is `System.Enum`. The keyword `struct` simply has another meaning here.

Comment: Hmm? No it doesn't. User-defined enums are both value types, and inherit from `System.Enum`. `enum Foo { A }` is a way of declaring a real value type which inherits from `System.Enum`.

Comment: @canton7 Well, it is a matter of terminology. Some types are written in C# as `struct S { /* … */ }`, and some are written as `enum E { /* … */ }`. Both kinds are value types. Whether you use the word "struct" for only the first kind (as I do, together with the official C# Language Specification), or you use the word "struct" as a common name for both kinds of value types, is just a matter of terminology. Related terminology question: Is the type `interface I { /* … */ }` a "class"? _Edit:_ After you edited your comment, it is closer to the terminology I use.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Your comment implies that the generic type constraint `struct` has another meaning when combined with the `System.Enum` constraint, which is what I'm disagreeing with. In the context of a generic type constraint, `struct` is the "value type constraint". I agree it is a matter of terminology and the keyword chosen here is confusing in this particular case, but my point is that a generic type constraint of `struct` has the same meaning whether combined with a constraint of `System.Enum` or not. I suspect we're both familiar with the C# spec and ECMA-335 here  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've simply got the order of things the wrong way around:

```
public class ChildClass<T> : BaseClass where T : Enum
```